# Mathematical modeling stackexchange

Tags: discussion

There is currently a proposal for a mathematical modeling stackexchange on Area51:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57490/mathematical-modeling?referrer=B5TWQ70QNWlDGxDR-o9vQA2

This is intended to have no overlap with statsSE; questions that are on-topic on one site should be off topic on the other. With that said, the site is still in the definition phase, so it needs people to post suggested mathematical modeling questions that they would like to see answered in the future. These questions can then be voted on by others (a 5 vote limit) to decide what the site should be about.

And again, this site should only be about mathematical modeling that is not statistical modeling. If you have any concerns, please post a comment.

Comment: Wouldn't this proposal overlap with Mathematics SE?

Comment: Other sources of comments: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10194.